# How to get an Expression from a Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, rules

I am developing a rules engine where the rules are setup in the Database with this design:

"PropertyName" "Operator" "PropertyValue" (for e.g.: data.employee.salary = 10000). This is run against a main class that has data as a property, which in fact points to a nested class called Data and the 'data' inner class in turn has a property called employee which maps to an Employee inner class that has a property of salary which is string right now.

This is part of the RulesEngine code I have coded that uses ExpressionTrees:

```
    // Loop through each of the rules per Ruleset and compile them against the properties of the supplied T object.
            //NOTE: The values in the database column 'PropertyName' should match exactly with the properties of the T class. ​
            rules.ForEach(rule =>​
            {​
                var genericType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));​
              //  var key = MemberExpression.Property(genericType, rule.PropertyName);​
                var key = CreateExpression(typeof(T), rule.PropertyName);​ //rule.PropertyName== 'data.employee.salary' 
                var propertyType = GetProp(typeof(T), rule.PropertyName).PropertyType;      // System.String          ​
                ​
                var value = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(rule.PropertyValue, propertyType));​ //"10000"
​`               if (rule.Operator != ExpressionType.Lambda && rule.Operator != ExpressionType.Default) //This covers both '=' and '<>' or anything Binary-ish Operators setup in the Rules table.​
                {​
                    var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(rule.Operator, key, value);​
                    compiledExpTreeRules.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(key, genericType).Compile());​
                }​

            static LambdaExpression CreateExpression(Type type, string propertyName)
            {​
                    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");​
                    Expression body = param;​
                    foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))​
                    {​
                        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);​
                    }​
                    return Expression.Lambda(body, param);​
            //return MemberExpression.Property(body, propertyName);​
        }
```

The problem I am having is I am returning an Expression.Lambda from my CreateExpression() method. I had to write this method because my T input class has nested classes within and hence properties and the rules can be configured in the database, at the leaf property level of an innermost nested class.

When I try to execute this line it gives me an error:

```
var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(rule.Operator, key, value);
```

How do I make binary expression when I already know the Lambda expression, which is the 'key' parameter? That key in the MakeBinary parameter list is erroring out. I tried key.body as well but I just don't know how to either 1) Make CreateExpression() return MemberExpression.Property or 2) When it returns an lambda expression of type x=>x.innnerclass1.prop1, how can I use this as 'key' and make a BinaryExpression? I have the lambda, I have the operator (coming from the db) and I have the value but I am struggling to build a BinaryExpression out of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Can you start by saying what error you get?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit confusing but it sounds like you have three things in hand:

- A lambda expression `lambda` with parameter `x` and body `x.i.p`.
- An expression `value`
- A binary operator kind -- let's suppose it is "addition".

And what you want is to construct the lambda for `x => x.i.p + value`, is that right?

To do that you'd say

```
// Given values:
LambdaExpression lambda = whatever;
Expression value = whatever;    
ExpressionType operator = whatever;
// Computed values:
Expression key = lambda.Body;
List<ParameterExpression> ps = lambda.Parameters;
BinaryExpression binop = Expression.MakeBinary(operator, key, value);
LambdaExpression newLambda = Expression.Lambda(binop, ps);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Sorry, it was a long winding question. Yes, I think I misspoke about the line of error. You are absolutely right and so, I changed the line to  var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(rule.Operator, key.Body, value);   But the next line where I do compiledExpTreeRules.Add..., is actually erroring out.  The error is: Expression Of Type 'System.Func'2 cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'.

Comment: When I had this line of code when there were no nested classes:  var key = MemberExpression.Property(genericType, rule.PropertyName);, this line never errors out: compiledExpTreeRules.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(key, genericType).Compile());​ BUT when I get the key as : var key = CreateExpression(typeof(T), rule.PropertyName);​, the same line throws the above error.

Comment: I am actually struggling to format my above comments, to make it readable. I am entering two spaces but I am not getting the line break. My apologies.

Comment: @Ram_P: There are no line breaks in SO comments, sorry! What you can do though to make it slightly more readable is to use "``" back ticks to `format code like this`.

Comment: OK. Thanks:-).  ``var key = MemberExpression.Property(genericType, rule.PropertyName);``  followed by `` compiledExpTreeRules.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(key, genericType).Compile());​  does NOT error out.

Comment: But ``var key = CreateExpression(typeof(T), rule.PropertyName);​`` followed by ``compiledExpTreeRules.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(key, genericType).Compile()); errors out with the error: ' Expression Of Type 'System.Func'2 cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean''. I am kind of puzzled why, as I am building a BinaryExpression

Comment: I think I have butchered this question and my code. Sorry. Let me go through the code again.

Comment: It sounds like you have just swapped some arguments somewhere. Sounds like you are passing a compiled expression to a function that is expecting an expression type.

Comment: @Ram_P: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting might help.

Comment: Thanks much, Eric! I have visited this site a billion times and I have  read comments here that shaped my career and yet, I was trying to format a line break in my comments. One of those days i guess. Yes, I think I have definitely swapped a few parameters.  I will figure it out. But truly appreciate your help!